# Content Provider for Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, android-contentprovider

Does Adobe Flex have provide a Content Provider for sharing data between two applications?

If not, is there an alternative way for Flex apps to share information without being connected to the internet?

Thanks

-edit: This is for two mobile apps; on the same tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Flex is a front-end client solution only.  It does not provide a way to share data between 2 applications unless you can have both applications know of each other's IP and can connect to each other directly (ie. without a firewall stopping it).  You can do this using the Socket class.

Other than that, you'll need some kind of middleware solution to transfer the data between the 2 clients.

And having Flex without the internet doesn't really work, unless you are using Air, at which point you still probably need some kind of data and that could be stored in a local SQLite database (that Air provides).

Comment: In that case, if you want both phone to talk to each other, you *definitely* need some kind of middleware to get both of them to talk to each other.  You can still use SQLite for mobile apps though if you want to "save" data locally until the app has internet access and can then save it to the server.

Comment: Both apps are on the same device, sorry

Comment: Hm, I've never tried it, but it is possible to share data between applications on the desktop using SQLite since it's essentially a file.  As long as both apps have permission to that file, everything is good.  I'm not sure for mobile though, it's something to try out.  However, if both apps run at the same time, I'm not sure how that would work...  Again, you'll need to try it out.